# Undefined/unused variable or unintended indent

Tags: python

I keep getting either these 2. If I manage to fix one, the other shows up.

This will get the undefined/unused variables error for quotes.

```
import random
def primary():
  print("Keep it logically awesome.")
 
  f = open("quotes.txt")
  quotes = f.readlines()
  f.close()

last = len (quotes) - 1
rnd = random.randint(0, last)

  print(quotes[rnd])

if __name__== "__main__":
primary()
```

If I simply remove all spaces from `print (quotes[rnd])` then I get "unexpected indent"

Comment: You should also indent `primary()` under `if __name__== "__main__":`.
`

Comment: You also need to fix the intent for `primary()`. You need to intent `last = len (quotes) - 1` and the next line

Answer (score 1):

the correct code would be as shown below.

You have to intent in a few places.

```
import random
def primary():
    print("Keep it logically awesome.")

    f = open("quotes.txt")
    quotes = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    last = len (quotes) - 1  #this shud be intented
    rnd = random.randint(0, last) #this shud also be intented

    print(quotes[rnd]) #this shud be intented

if __name__== "__main__":
    primary() #if statements shud always be intented
```

An alternate way to write the single line if statement would be

```
if __name__== "__main__": primary()
```

For additional information on indentation,  please refer to:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/amp/

https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Comment: Single line ifs are legal but make code harder to read I don't recommend recommending them to beginners.

Comment: Also, that link to python 2.0 docs is woefuly out of date. The concept is still mostly valid I'm sure, but I'd hesitate to trust any of the detailed stuff on those pages.

Comment: My bad on the link to python 2. Will update it with python 3 documentation. Was on my my mobile. Still no excuse to post out of date links

Comment: Python 2.0 no less :)

Comment: back on my computer. Updated the references. Sorry about that. Trying to be active on the community using a phone sometimes can get you in trouble :)

Comment: Tell me about it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def primary():
    print("Keep it logically awesome.")

    f = open("quotes.txt")
    quotes = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    last = len(quotes) - 1
    rnd = random.randint(0, last)

    print(quotes[rnd])

if __name__== "__main__":
  primary()
```

Comment: This will always crash

Comment: There I fixed the indentation

Comment: Now it's just like all the other answers, but posted much later

Comment: So? At least now it's not misleading

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def primary():
    print("Keep it logically awesome.")
 
    f = open("quotes.txt")
    quotes = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    last = len(quotes) - 1
    rnd = random.randint(0, last)
    print(quotes[rnd])

if __name__== "__main__":
    primary()
```

Hope this will be helpful for you. Enjoy!